# Combine multiple is in when clause in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Suppose I have the following:

```
fun makeSound(val animal: Animal) = when(animal) {
  is Lion -> animal.roar()
  is TRex -> animal.roar()
  is Cow -> animal.moo()
}
```

Usually I would simplify this by simply adding a `RoaringAnimal` interface and asking `is RoaringAnimal`. But is there another way of combining multiple `is` clauses into one?

Comment: why would you want something that combines `is Lion` and `is TRex` here? Isn't it already easy enough to just use it the way you show? Otherwise I would rather update your hierarchy if possible... (side-note: `val` is probably wrong here and `=` requires an exhaustive `when`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally you can combine the clauses as shown in Yoni's answer.

But in the specific case that `roar` is defined on `Lion` and `TRex`, but not on `Animal`, you can't.

This is because the compiler inserts a smart cast:

```
is Lion -> animal.roar()
```

is really

```
is Lion -> (animal as Lion).roar()
```

but in `is Lion, is TRex ->` clause, it wouldn't know what cast to insert.

In principle the compiler could be extended to handle such cases by inserting another `when`:

```
is Lion, is TRex -> animal.roar()
```

would become

```
is Lion, is TRex -> when(animal) {
    is Lion -> animal.roar() // works as before
    is TRex -> animal.roar()
}
```

but I wouldn't expect this to happen

Comment: "In principle the compiler could be extended to handle such cases .." Yup, and actually this was exactly what I thought was the behavior. Thanks for the explanation about the compiler not knowing which smart cast to insert.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**: the answer below was written before the question specified that `roar` was a method on the `animal` parameter. As the question now stands, the answer below will no longer work, however it still shows how multiple conditions can be combined in one line in a `when` statement.

You can combine them:

```
fun makeSound(animal: Animal) = when(animal) {
  is Lion, is TRex -> roar()
  is Cow -> moo()
}
```

Comment: How will this work? Will this not just catch a generic `Animal` type?

Comment: `roar` will only be called if you pass in a `Lion` or `TRex`.  What do you mean by "catch" exactly?  I wonder if you need to slightly clarify your question?

Comment: Ah, yes. I was not precise in my question. I modified it now.

Comment: As Alexey says, now you've updated your question to specify that `roar` is a method on `Lion` and on `TRex`, then no, there is no (nice) way of doing this without a new interface or base class. (You could use Reflection but that wouldn't be a good idea here.)

Answer (score 3):

```
fun makeSound(val animal: Animal) = when(animal) {
  Lion, TRex -> animal.roar()
  Cow -> animal.moo()
}
```

You don't need 'is'. Just have it comma separator which works as OR here.

Answer (score -2):

What you are doing here looks like a [code smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/switch-statements) to me. Why don't you use polymorphism for this type of problem?

```
interface Animal {
    fun makeSound()
}
class Lion : Animal {
    override fun makeSound() { println("roar") }
}
class Trex : Animal {
    override fun makeSound() { println("ROAAAARRRR") }
}
class Cow : Animal {
    override fun makeSound() { println("moo") }
}

fun makeSound(animal: Animal) {
    animal.makeSound()
    // due tue "late binding", this will automatically call the correct method - no need to check what kind of animal it is! 
}
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, using a interface is absolutely possible. However, the question is not one of best practice but rather what is possible in Kotlin.